# how to bind function processing with updateprogress control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database, c#-4.0, updatepanel, updateprogress

On click on button function are not getting fired. Why this is happening.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"
                    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                   ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-progress.gif"
                   />
                <br />
                Please Wait. This will take few minutes.
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" 
                    Text="Update" 
                    onclick="btnUpdate_Click" 
                    Width="100px" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

code behind :

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    trunc();
    ConsumerUpld(FileUpload1);     
}
```

`ConsumerUpld(fileupld)` function updates table in database

Answer (score 0):

Everything seam fine, so I tested your code by replacing it by a  `btnUpdate.Text = "updated";`

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnUpdate.Text = "updated";
    //trunc();
    //ConsumerUpld(FileUpload1);
}
```

Everything run smoothly, so your problems is within one of the 2 functions you call.

When an error occurs during an async postback, it show on the button of the browser page (the way it show depend of your browser). You should try to debug it with breakpoints or comment out the update panel to see what is happening.